# Display a fraction in IOS

Tags: html, ios, string, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSString representation of fractions using unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918516/nsstring-representation-of-fractions-using-unicode)
>   [Using Fractions On Websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671752/using-fractions-on-websites)

I am porting my application from `android` to `IOS`. In my android app i use this code to display `fractions`

```
   Html.fromHtml("<sup>" + top + "</sup>/<sub>" + bottom + "</sub>");
```

But I dont know how to do this in `iOS`

Hers what the Html code above looks like in android see the picture
[image: pic]

Comment: Though you may be able to do it with attributed strings now in ios6, though sub and super-script aren't listed in the UIKit constants reference.

Comment: This does not seem to be primarily OS dependent. Rather, it depends on the desired appearance, on the browser, and on the font. So I suggest that is a duplicate of questions about rendering fractions in web pages in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am correct that you are asking for formatting a string, then please find the answer below.
Considering the values as float,

```
NSString *fraction = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f / %f", top, bottom];
```

And you can set the value to UILabel for showing purpose.

Comment: I am sorry I should have clarified the function above makes the number look like 1 / 2 buts the 1 is higher up and the 2 is lower down. Let me find a away to display this on here